# Radius and Diameter Tree Proof

Tags: graph-theory, trees

How do I mathematically prove "Radius in a tree is not necessarily half it's diameter"? Even though there are examples that justify this but is there a mathematical proof for this?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question - a simple counterexample proves this: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GraphRadius.html

Answer (score 1):

"Suppose the radius is always half the diameter" is an invitation for a counterexample. I would restate the definitions and follow with a note stating that the radius is not necessarily half the diameter. Use an example to illustrate -- a path of length 3 perhaps.